# Publish MarkerArray in an already existing Marker Topic

Tags: ros, markerarray

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,
I have a node that publishes a MarkerArray Topic:

```
ros::Publisher obst_pub = nh.advertise<visualization_msgs::MarkerArray>("/obstacles_markers", 1);
```

which contains my obstacles. Then I have another node that calculates the width of obstacles through the laser scanner and put it in a MarkerArray as well.

Now the problem is that I want to publish this new MarkerArray into the other existing topic "obstacles_markers", is that possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/374856/publish-markerarray-in-an-already-existing-marker-topic/) by [UndefinedDuck](https://answers.ros.org/users/71255/undefinedduck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Now the problem is that I want to publish this new MarkerArray into the other existing topic "obstacles_markers"

that's not really a problem.

> is that possible?

yes, of course.

Publish-subscribe is a *many-to-many* interaction pattern/style.

Subscribers do not know who published a message, nor do publishers know who subscribers are.

In fact, publishers do not know anything about subscribers (nor the other way around).

So it's perfectly possible to publish to the same topic from different nodes.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-03-28**:
Perhaps you've always thought about topics as being *channels* to which only sender and receiver are connected, each on one end (ie: the beginning and the end). But that's not how topics works (or: you're not restricted to such a topology).

**Comment by [UndefinedDuck](https://answers.ros.org/users/71255/undefinedduck/) on 2021-03-28**:
So I can define a topic in the other node with the same name of the first one and publish on it without having conflicts?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-03-28**:
Isn't that what I wrote in my answer?

As long as the types are *exactly* the same, you can publish with as many publishers on a the same topic as you'd like.

**Comment by [UndefinedDuck](https://answers.ros.org/users/71255/undefinedduck/) on 2021-03-28**:
Ok got it, I'm a totally beginner so thank you